# Is there sny module for auto-posting on social media networks?

Tags: 7

Is there any module to automatically post contents of our Drupal site into social media networks (e.g. Facebook, Twitter)?

For WordPress there is the Social Networks Auto-Poster plugin. What is the equivalent module for Drupal?

Comment: There are many, easy to find. Tried phrase "Drupal post to Facebook" on Google? Or "drupal post to twitter"? Even "drupal post to social media" gives some neat manuals.

Answer (score 3):

There is no module for doing that in Drupal as far as I know. However, there is a way you can achieve this.

You can create an rss feed ( you can use drupal default feed, syndication or views) and then use a service called twitterfeed

See [tutorial here](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/drupal-social-networks/)

Answer (score 1):

I know its maybe a late answer but you can try this module for drupal 8 :

> Autopost social is a module to publish posts to multi Social network
>   (Facebook, Twitter) when you add/edit a new content.
>   https://www.drupal.org/project/autopost_social